# About Armor Compensation and EANM / ANP

Tags: eve-online

I'm a new Eve player (~1 month old), and I'm looking into Armor Compensation and EANM / ANP (T1/meta4), and there are few things I don't understand.

1. Does Armor Compensation work for ANP as well or just EANM?
2. Without any AC skills, `'Refuge' Adaptive Nano Plating I` gives 15.36% resist, `Prototype Energized Adaptive Nano Membrane I` gives 15%, now everything I read said EANMs are better than ANP, but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you to play around in [EFT](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=24359) or [Pyfa](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=247609), this is extremely useful in general and you can easily find out the first question with those programs.

Both, ANP and EANM are affected by the armor compensation skills. Unlike the shield compensation skills which only affect passive hardeners and are pretty useless, the armor compensation skills are quite useful.

The statement that the enegized version is better is based on the Tech 2 versions of these modules where there is a difference of 20% vs. 15.4%, in the  meta 4 versions this is not the case and the ANP is even slightly better.

Comment: The main difference between Adaptive Nano Plating (ANP) and Energized Adaptive Nano Membrane(EANM) is that, at Tech 2 levels anyway, EANM will give you more of a resistance bonus, but at the cost of CPU. ANP only costs 1 Power Grid, whereas EANM costs 1 PG and 36 CPU